# Facebook App Setup

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created FB application that use iframes, and it's working okay, as it should, BUT I need to check from what page is calling it.

I want different pages to pass different variables to that iframe location.

I already know how to set up it to three levels ( original page, application page, and on tab page, with different display content ), but I need to check from what page it's called.

I am thinking that it can be done in 2 ways:

1 way: Find way to pass specific variable based on page that is using this application as tab, and then redirect it to right location

2 way: Find way to create new application outside facebook ( maybe API or something ) and then enter all those values including: App name, app link that have this variable included, app tab link, using iframe and not FBML...

I will love to use 2. way...

I'm not asking you to show me code, I know that I need to do my job, I'm not asking you to do it for me, I'm just asking for help, for directions from someone who already create something like this, to point me to right direction where can I find way...

Also, please don't tell me to read bunch of stuffs, like FB Documentation or whole book that have all other "not-used-here" stuffs, I need specific part where there is a word about this...

If someone know anything about this, write it here...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "page" parameter is passed along within the "new" signed_request parameter on (iframe) tabs. You get what you need for "free" ;)

> page: A JSON object containing the page
>   id string, the liked boolean if the
>   user has liked the page, the admin
>   boolean if the user is an admin. Only
>   available if your app is an iframe
>   loaded in a Page tab.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Comment: Yes, that's it... I already find it, before answer, but thank you!